# Javascript network how to use labels instead of numbers

Tags: javascript, d3.js, graph, visualization

I want to use [this graph](https://bl.ocks.org/emeeks/3a54620a4751a7d68c1e) code, however the example uses numbers as nodes, like this:

```
source,target,weight
1,3,5
1,8,3
1,9,3
1,12,3
```

I find that numbers are not that visually informative so I want to lable the nodes, so using:

```
source,target,weight
node_name_1,node_name_2,5
node_name_1,node_name_3,3
node_name_2,node_name_3,3
node_name_1,node_name_4,3
```

However when using text as nodes I get the following error:

```
SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'node_name_1' of undefined or null reference
```

When I go to this line:

```
nodes.forEach(function (node) {
  node.module = result[node.id] <-- this is the line that causes the error
});
```

Any ideas how I can adjust this code so that I can use labels as input instead of numbers?

*I'm quite a beginner in JS*

---

**EDIT**
As shown by gerardo the code is working (at least with his .csv) however using my own csv will not work:

```
source,target,weight
SomeOrganism,LikeCoffee,18
SomeOtherOrganism,LikeCoffee,4
WellAnotherOne,TheSunIsShining,1
WellAnotherOne,ThisIsNotGood,1
IHopeThis,ThisIsNotGood,1
SomeOtherOrganism,IHopeThis,2
SomeOrganism,testing,2
SomeOrganism,NeedSomeHelp,8
SomeOrganism,AflowerisNice,9
SomeOrganism,IsThisWorking,2
SomeOrganism,ILikeBread,4
SomeOrganism,MeltyButter,2
AflowerisNice,NeedSomeHelp,2
SugerIsSweet,SomeOrganism,1
NeedSomeHelp,ILikeBread,1
SomeOtherOrganism,ILikeBread,1
```

Comment: I found no error using names: https://bl.ocks.org/anonymous/935bf880896906cb3b97eeb6eb70ba48/8b937464f56b750dd3c3f95f7623406b9abc23f0 Voting to close this question.

Comment: hmm when I use your example csv it works fine @GerardoFurtado

Comment: Could you please try it with the csv I added in my question @GerardoFurtado

Comment: I figured out the problem: A weight of "1" will produce the error @GerardoFurtado

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the error: the original CSV has several `1` as weight.

Comment: hmm strange when I replace all the "1" weights for "2" it works @GerardoFurtado, but I'm wondering why